# Import adodbapi: No module named 'process_connect_string'

Tags: python

adodbapi and pywin32 modules installed.

When I import it, it does not work and shows the following error:

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 import adodbapi as ado
>
> C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\adodbapi__init__.py in ()
>        20     _makeByteBuffer = bytes
>        21 
>   ---> 22 from .adodbapi import connect, Connection, **version**, dateconverter, Cursor
>        23 
>        24 def Binary(aString):
>
> C:\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py in ()
>        35 import os
>        36 
>   ---> 37 import process_connect_string
>        38 from . import ado_consts as adc
>        39 import apibase as api
>
> ImportError: No module named 'process_connect_string'

I searched and did not find any module in python named 'process_connect_string'

win7 64bit, python3.5.1 64bit

Answer (score 0):

You have installed wrong version of **adodbapi**. Please follow the below 2 steps to eliminate the error.

1. Ensure you have downloaded and installed **pywin32** from
   http://sf.net/projects/pywin32. Here select the installer according
   to your Python version.
2. Download **adodbapi** from http://sf.net/projects/adodbapi. Unpack the zip. Go to the folder containing unzipped files. Run the command **python setup.py install**. This will install **adodbapi** in your system.

Run your program now. If it does not work, copy the above folder to *lib\site-packages* of your Anaconda.